# Writing R program using Biostrings to convert nucleotide sequences to protein sequence

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a .fasta file with many different sequences. My goal is to use the Biostrings package to convert each individual sequence to the amino acid sequence for it.
The .fasta file looks like this:

```
>Sequence 1
AAATTTGGGCCC
>Sequence 2
TTTGGGCCCAAA
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [translate function](https://rdrr.io/bioc/Biostrings/man/translate.html) will do what you want:

```r
library(Biostrings)

`Sequence 1` <- DNAString("AAATTTGGGCCC")
`Sequence 2` <- DNAString("TTTGGGCCCAAA")

seq_1 <- translate(`Sequence 1`, no.init.codon=TRUE)
seq_1
#> 4-letter AAString object
#> seq: KFGP

seq_2 <- translate(`Sequence 2`, no.init.codon=TRUE)
seq_2
#> 4-letter AAString object
#> seq: FGPK
```

To read in the entire fasta file:

```r
seqs <- Biostrings::readDNAStringSet("file.fasta", format = "fasta", use.names = TRUE)
seqs_translated <- translate(seqs, no.init.codon = TRUE)
seqs_translated
#> AAStringSet object of length 2:
#>     width seq                               names               
#> [1]     4 KFGP                              Sequence 1
#> [2]     4 FGPK                              Sequence 2
```

### Edit

Your problem translating your fasta file is that the sequences use the ['full' alphabet](http://www.hgmd.cf.ac.uk/docs/nuc_lett.html), not just ATCG - you have 'No calls' ("N"), gaps ("-"), and ambivalent/unresolved calls e.g. "K" (Guanine or Thymine). I found these using sed:

```
grep -v ">" SEQUENCE_orf1ab.fasta | sed 's/[ATCG]//g' | sed '/^$/d'
# explanation: remove lines beginning with ">"
# then remove all A/T/C/G's and blank lines
# what you have left is causing the "not a base" error
```

If you remove these "non-base" bases using e.g.

```
sed '/^>/! s/[-NYRKW]//g' SEQUENCE_orf1ab.fasta > test.fasta 
#explanation: in lines not beginning with ">", substitute all of the characters "-NYRKW" with nothing (i.e. delete them)
```

then the file is translated without issue:

```
seqs <- Biostrings::readDNAStringSet("test.fasta", format = "fasta", use.names = TRUE)
seqs_translated <- translate(seqs, no.init.codon = TRUE)
seqs_translated

#>  AAStringSet object of length 91:
#>       width seq                              names               
#>  [1]  7095 MESLVPGFNEKTHVQ...KTTELLFLVMFLLT MZ505877.1 |Sever...
#>  [2]  7095 MESLVPGFNEKTHVQ...KTTELLFLVMFLLT MZ020653.1 |Sever...
#>  [3]  7092 MESLVPGFNEKTHVQ...KTTELLFLVMFLLT MW988268.1 |Sever...
#>  [4]  7095 MESLVPGFNEKTHVQ...KTTELLFLVMFLLT MW928277.1 |Sever...
#>  [5]  7095 MESLVPGFNEKTHVQ...KTTELLFLVMFLLT MW885875.1 |Sever...
#>  ...   ... ...
#> [87]  7095 MESLVPGFNEKTHVQ...KTTELLFLVMFLLT MN996529.1 |Sever...
#> [88]  7095 MESLVPGFNEKTHVQ...KTTELLFLVMFLLT MN996530.1 |Sever...
#> [89]  7095 MESLVPGFNEKTHVQ...KTTELLFLVMFLLT MN996531.1 |Sever...
#> [90]  7094 MESLVPGFNEKTHVQ...KTTELLFLVMFLLT MN988713.1 |Sever...
#> [91]  7095 MESLVPGFNEKTHVQ...KTTELLFLVMFLLT MN975262.1 |Sever...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue I have is that the sequences are much longer than that. I am hoping to load them from the fasta instead of manually typing each one.

Comment: I keep receiving the following error:

```Error in .Call2("DNAStringSet_translate", x, skip_code, dna_codes[codon_alphabet],  : 
  in 'x[[3]]': not a base at pos 11023```

I am not sure how to fix this because I checked the sequence and position 11023 has the base C. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Whenever I run the ```sed '/^>/! s/[-NYRKW]//g' SEQUENCE_orf1ab.fasta > test.fasta``` command, I receive the following error: ```Error: unexpected string constant in "sed '/^>/! s/[-NYRKW]//g'"```

I am not sure how to fix this issue and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Weird. So the command `grep -v ">" SEQUENCE_orf1ab.fasta | sed 's/[ATCG]//g' | sed '/^$/d'` worked, but then you get the unexpected string constant error when you try to run `sed '/^>/! s/[-NYRKW]//g' SEQUENCE_orf1ab.fasta > test.fasta`?

Comment: The first command gives me the following error: ```Error: unexpected string constant in "grep -v ">""```

Comment: Are you running these commands from the R console, or from a terminal?

Comment: That was the issue. Fixed it now. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: No problem - glad to help - but in future, you will very likely find more help on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ rather than on stackoverflow, which is more geared towards professional programmers and their questions. The bioinformaticians there are more likely to help you with advice on the best approach to take to achieve your goal (e.g. align and translate with MAFFT/clustal might be easier, depending on your goal).

Comment: Understood. As for this question, I wanted to ask one more thing. I have created the object and I would like to save it again to a fasta or txt file. Upon research, I found the following command ```saveRDS(seqs_translated, file = "aa.fasta")``` but unfortunately when I save it, there are a bunch of random characters instead of the actual amino acid string set I view in the console. Would you have a recommendation for what's the best way to save this file? Thank you again.

Comment: Best way is `writeXStringSet(seqs_translated, "translated.fasta")`